# Github Syntax Highlighting On Wiki

Tags: github, syntax, wiki, highlighting

I've read this page:
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/

And everywhere else on Github I can do syntax highlighting inside markdown very simply.

However, on my recent project the syntax highlighting has completely given up on Wiki pages, I can't get it work at all.  Everywhere I look the only answer seems to be "make sure you specify the language".  It seems like no matter how I specify the language the syntax highlighting doesn't work.

Example page:
https://github.com/ClickSimply/Nano-SQL/wiki/3.-Advanced

[image: Example Page Screenshot]

However, on that exact same project the highlighting is working as expected in the ReadMe
https://github.com/ClickSimply/Nano-SQL

Seriously out of ideas here, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Reached out directly to Github support, this is an issue they're currently working to resolve.